# Angular 17.1 Signal Inputs on directive?

Tags: angular, signals, angular2-directives

I'm able to use the new Angular's 17.1 Signal Inputs as follows:

```js
{
    public value: InputSignal<string> = input.required<string>();
}
```

And while it works on components, it does not on my directives. It however seems to be supported according to [this post](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/863be4b6981dc60ca0610b0e61d2ba1f5759e2a3#:%7E:text=%60%60%60ts%0A%40directive(%7B..%7D)%0Aexport%20class%20MyDir%20%7B%0A%20%20firstName%20%3D%20input%3Cstring%3E()%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//%20string%7Cundefined%0A%20%20lastName%20%3D%20input.required%3Cstring%3E()%3B%20%20%20%20//%20string%0A%20%20age%20%3D%20input(0)%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//%20number%0A%60%60%60):

```
@directive({..})
export class MyDir {
  firstName = input<string>();            // string|undefined
  lastName = input.required<string>();    // string
  age = input(0);                         // number
```

For instance, here is my directive:

```js
@Directive({
    selector: '[appMyDirective]',
    standalone: true,
    exportAs: 'myDirective',
})
export class MyDirective {
    public value: InputSignal<string> = input.required<string>();
}
```

The compiler will complain:

```js
  <app-my-component
    appMyDirective
    [value]="aValue"
  </app-my-component>
```

I get an error like this:

```bash
Error: example.component.html:14:6 - error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'unique symbol' can't be used to index type 'Signal<string>'.
  Property '["@angular/core".ɵINPUT_SIGNAL_BRAND_WRITE_TYPE]' does not exist on type 'Signal<string>'.

14     [value]="aValue"
```

Since the Signal input feature was released last week, it might be a bug, but I'm open to suggestions if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Have you updated angular language server plugin to latest?

Comment: everything is in v17.1.1, btwI however realized the post to be related to the v17.2.0-next.0. Perhaps it's simply not ready yet for directives. I'm just surprised to see it working on components but not directives

Comment: I have tested on version ^17.1.0-next.0 it is working as expected.

Comment: Thank you for checking, then I'm doing something wrong with my directive

Comment: I'm to reproduice on Stackblitz, I might have to flush the cache and try again... https://stackblitz-starters-bu5hny.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing the cache and rebuilding the app, the compilation error is gone but I'm still having a warning on webstorm :
[image]

As (warningapart), the code works as expected, I have now to understand why webstorm is complaining, but this is another issue.

[EDIT]: Upgrading webstorm fixed the issue...